# custom control design-time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to create my own TabControl-class with design-time suppport.

This is my designer:

```
public class TabListDesigner : ParentControlDesigner
{
    protected TabList TabListControl { get { return this.Control as TabList; } }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case 0x7b: // WM_CONTEXTMENU
                this.OnContextMenu(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
                break;
            default:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;
        }
    }

    protected override bool GetHitTest(Point point)
    {
        return this.TabListControl.HitTest(this.TabListControl.PointToClient(point)) != null;
    }

    protected override void OnPaintAdornments(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaintAdornments(pe);
        ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(pe.Graphics, this.Control.ClientRectangle);
    }

    public override void InitializeNewComponent(IDictionary defaultValues)
    {
        base.InitializeNewComponent(defaultValues);
        this.AddTabListPage();
        this.AddTabListPage();
    }

    protected virtual void AddTabListPage()
    {
        IDesignerHost host = (IDesignerHost)this.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost));

        if (host != null)
        {
            using (DesignerTransaction transaction = host.CreateTransaction(string.Format("Add TabListPage to '{0}'", this.TabListControl.Name)))
            {
                try
                {
                    TabListPage page = (TabListPage)host.CreateComponent(typeof(TabListPage));
                    MemberDescriptor controlsProperty = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this.TabListControl)["Controls"];

                    this.RaiseComponentChanging(controlsProperty);

                    this.TabListControl.Add(page);
                    this.TabListControl.Controls.Add(page);

                    this.RaiseComponentChanged(controlsProperty, null, null);

                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch
                {
                    transaction.Cancel();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the designer, I add my Tabcontrol to the form and the 2 TabPages show properly. Now I test the project and the 2 Tabpages disappear. I go back to the designer and the Tabpages aren't there anymore. Why?

Comment: Have you tried setting up an environment to [debug your design time controls?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996457.aspx) Helps a lot being able to step through the code like you would normally, can highlight issues nicely if you follow the flow.

Comment: I think the problem is with the serialization. Your example created a TabList with 2 tabs at the beginning, but these two tabs were not serialized. Check the "#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code" region in your form header file. If you can not find there something like TabList->Items->Add(TabPage1); then your pages was serialized.

Comment: I don't know, but one thing looks weird to me: you add the same page first to TabListControl and then again to TabListControl.Controls.

Answer (score 0):

I once created a control designer, not the ones that the form designer uses, but more like an actual form designer for a single control. I don't remember much from the project, but I do remember having the excact same problem, and that I had to alert visual studio that I had changed a value in some sort of way.

Once you save the designer tab, visual studio will go ahead and convert that change to code depending on the language, and write it in the designer file of your form. You can also write your own specific code generator using codeDom, but that is heavily advanced.

It's not quite what you want, but I bet that the problem is related, so bear with me. The only example I could find on the field was an acient c# project called "Shape designer" or something. I got it from a light blue website. I did a bit of searching, but I was not able to find the page. Anyways, the code was well documented, and he explained your problem quite throughly.

I also have my project, which is a tab-ish thing which animates between the pages when you go to another page. It's in vb.net, not as well documented, but you might want to have a glimpse at it.

[Here's the project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69377299/Pages.zip),
[here's a image of the designer](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69377299/PageDesigner.png), and a
[animated gif of the end result](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69377299/PageControl.gif)

EDIT:

In my project, in the "DesignerControl.vb" file, at line 187:

```
' The controldesigner don't always save properties which are changed directly :/
Private Sub SetValue(itm As Item, pName$, val As Object)
    Dim Prop As PropertyDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(itm.Page)(pName)
    If Prop IsNot Nothing AndAlso Prop.PropertyType Is val.GetType Then Prop.SetValue(itm.Page, val)
End Sub
```